# Find an asymptotically tight bound for $\sum_{k=1}^nk^r\log^s(k)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms, upper-lower-bounds

I have an exam coming up that I'm studying for and I'm somewhat stumped by a couple problems. I need to derive an asymptotically tight bound for the following summation:

Assume $r$ and $s$ are constants such that $r,s\geq 0$.

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^r\log^s(k)$$

So far I have come up with

$$0\leq f(x)\leq(\sum_{k=1}^nn^r)(\sum_{k=1}^n\log^s(n))$$

$$f(x)\leq(n^{r+1})(n\log^s(n))$$

$$f(x)\leq(n^{r+2})(\log^s(n))$$

However, I'm getting told these are not asymptotically tight bounds and I need to correct this answer. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Perhaps compare your sum to $\int_1^n x^r\log^s(x)\,dx$

Comment: I assume by $f(x)$, you mean $f(r,s,n)$, since there's no $x$ in your expressions?

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, one can use integral approximation of sums. We have:

$$\int_{0}^{n}x^r\ln^s(x)dx\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^r\ln^s(x)\leq \int_{1}^{n+1}x^r\ln^s(x)dx$$

With indefinit integrals and integrating by parts:

$$\int x^r\ln^s(x)dx = \frac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1}\ln^s(x)-\frac{s}{r+1}\int x^r\ln^{s-1}(x)dx=\frac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1}\ln^s(x)-\frac{s}{r+1}\left(\frac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1}\ln^{s-1}(x)-(s-1)\int x^r\ln^{s-2}(x)dx\right)$$

Observe that: $$\frac{s}{r+1}\cdot ( \cdot \cdot \cdot)\in O\left(\frac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1}\ln^s(x)\right)=O\left(x^{r+1}\ln^s(x)\right)$$ when $x\to +\infty$. In other words $\frac{s}{r+1}(\cdot\cdot\cdot)$ is negligible in respect to $x^{r+1}\ln^s(x)$ for $x\to +\infty$.

We can conclude:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^r\ln^s(k)\in \Theta\left(n^{r+1}\cdot\ln^s(n)\right)$$

Comment: Hope you are familiar with big O ($O(...)$) and big theta ($\Theta(...)$) notation. Otherwise, let me know and I will add some clarification in my post.